# gnome-shell-extension app not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gnome-shell, wayland, gnome-shell-extension

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 with wayland disabled by default on my system. So I clean installed recommended proprietary nvidia-515 driver to switch to wayland. But this driver is rendering any extension app unusable, gnome-shell-extension-manager and gnome-extension-app in particular. On opening both app the app icon appear briefly in dock and then disappear and trying to open in the terminal gives the following error.

```js
Gdk-Message: 14:14:56.485: Error flushing display: Protocol error
```

I have seen same questions on many forums but didn't get any solution except some workaround that also don't works completely. I'll list out all the solutions that I've found and one of my own.

1. Install extension on xorg and switch back to wayland to use them. Not sure if this work completely but many seems to find it work but it somehow makes system more unstable.
2. Manually run gnome-extensions-app using the following command:

   ```js
   __EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES=/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json gnome-extensions-app
   ```

   This solutions only helps us to open extension GUI and toggles the extension on/off but doesn't allow us to manage the settings of extension.
3. Install the gnome-shell-extension-manager using flatpak after uninstalling apt version. It works for all extension but we still won't be able to configure it's settings. On clicking setting of any extension it disables the gnome-extension itself.

Though, I was able to enable the much needed gesture-improvement extension with it's default setting by following 3rd solution, I'm having really bad user experience while dealing with extensions. If you have good technical knowledge of why this is happening along with its fix and know about some other nvidia drivers that is stable with Ubuntu 22.04 wayland please let me know.

**Ps**- I'll also update this question once I found some better solution.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I apparently need use Wayland because of docking station driver issues with additional screens at work and I want to use gnome-shell-extension manager to get my "Vertical Workspaces" back on Ubuntu 22.04. I'd be grateful for anyone else to chip in with ideas. I'd rather not use flatpack as I just got rid of snap. Doesn't make sense for me

Comment: Update: Switched to xorg (x11) for testing purposes and the issue persists. The extension manager is able to start but as soon as I click on the window, the application disappears.